# Maven Classifier dependency doesn't resolve always

Tags: maven-3, nexus

We use Maven3.0.3 and we use classifier to resolve among dependency for three regions DEV/TEST/PROD.  Even though the Nexus maven rep has got the jars with all classifiers(DEV/TEST/PROD) it doesn't always get resolved. We had to build the specific classifier dependencies everytime to get it resolved.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: what was the actual fix ? You have accepted the answer but you did not mention the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to

- Run maven with `-X` to produce debug output that may help (see `mvn -help`). If the artifacts are there but are skipped there must be a reason. Try to find it in the debug outputs.
- Check the update policy (for snapshot and releases) in your [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) - maybe your update is skipped because the update-policy is set to daily (which is the default) but you need "always" because your dependencies are deployed more often (SNAPSHOT).
- Try to run maven with `-X` to force an update of your dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your dependencies are snapshots, the problem may be the same as what I was seeing: that the snapshot resolves to the latest found in the repository, and it looks for your classifier within that build. So if a different classifier from the one you're looking for was the last to be built, dependency resolution fails. This would seem to be a bug in how Maven is doing its resolution, which appears to have been fixed in Maven 3.0.4 (my only other Maven install is 2.2.x so I can't say for certain whether this is broken in 3.0.3 still).

Also, it could be that you're using a version of say the dependency plugin which still has this problem. Make sure you don't have it pegged to something old.